# Compatibility With CH340 drivers on Horus?

Tags: drivers

I am having some troubles trying to install CH340 drivers for an Arduino Nano from the [Arduino official page](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/4412955149586-If-your-board-does-not-appear-on-a-port-in-Arduino-IDE).
Then I tryied following [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ch340-drivers/all#linux) guide, but when I run `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0` I have the error: `chmod: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB0': No such file or directory` even though when I run
`sudo dmesg | grep ch34` I can see the log `[466332.874357] usb 1-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0`  but after `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` I can't find the serial port.

**NOTE:**
To be able to run `make` on the driver's folder, I had to install kernel headers with `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and update the build directory `sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`.

I used chatGPT a bit for troubleshooting but I fear to screw-up with the kernel.